Change order of summation
I need to change the summation order in the sum:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{ n m } F(k, n - mk)
$$
In Srivastava's book, I came across a similar formula
\begin{array}{c}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor} F(k, n - mk) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\lfloor k/m \rfloor} F(k - mn, n).
\end{array}
Is it possible to use the formula in any way to change the summation order in my sum?
I attempted to perform the substitution $mn=p$, but it did not yield any results.

Note that in the referred identity the arguments are always non-negative. This is not the case in the double sum which is to consider. We obtain assuming a non-negative integer $m$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}\,&\color{blue}{ \sum_{k=0}^{ n m } F(k, n - mk)}\\
&=\sum_{{0\leq k\leq mn<\infty}\atop{n\geq 0}}F(k,n-mk)\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n= \lceil k/m\rceil}^{\infty}F(k,n-mk)\tag{2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}F(k,n+\lceil k/m\rceil-mk)}\tag{3}
\end{align*}
Comment:

In (1) we write the index region of summation more conveniently to better see how to swap the sums.

In (2) we swap the sums and use the ceiling operator since $n\geq k/m$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ implies $n\geq \lceil k/m\rceil$.

In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $n=0$.



Thank you......

@Leox: You're welcome. :-)
